# Tab control in VB

Tags: tabs, vb6, tabcontrol

I'm working on a legacy VB6 application. I'm sure this probably relates to VB.NET so i will tag it, but please let me know if it's completely different(which I dont think it is) then I'll remove the tag to avoid confusion.

Here is my issue....

I have a Tab control with multiple tabs: 0 - 3. On TabStuff.Tab = 0, I have a few textboxes and comboboxes. The user uses keyboard TAB to move from Indexed controls. What happens is once they get to the last control which is a textbox called txtCity - and click keyboard TAB once more, it brings them to TabStuff.Tab=1.

My issue is I do VALIDATE on txtCity - I call a function that verifies that a couple of the fields aren't NULL and if one of the fields is in fact NULL then I show a MSgBox and try to setFocus on that control. But instead, when OK is clicked on msgbox, it goes to the next tab which is TabStuff.tab=1 which is not correct.

Here's some of my code...

```
Dim FirstName, City as String
flag=false

firstName = txtName.text
city = txtcity.text
if FirstName="" or isnull(FirstName) then 
     msgbox "Please enter Name"
     tabstuff.tab=0 
     txtname.setfocus
     exit sub
elseif city = "" or isnull(city) then
     msgbox "Please enter city"
     tabstuff.tab=0
     txtcity.setfocus
     exit sub
end if

flag=true
```

This code is in txtCITY_VALIDATE

So in case city was empty, it shows MsgBox, stays on Tab=0 and setfocus on that control, but instead it goes to the next tab=1 and sets focus on the first control of that tab.

EDIT:

in txtCITY_LostFocus

```
If Flag = False Then
    TabStuff.Tab = 0
    Exit Sub
End If
```

I added this but it still goes to tabstuff.tab=1 setting the focus on first control of the tab

EDIT 2:

In a new project i created txt1 and txt2 - i set TabIndex 0 and 1 respectively.

```
Private Sub Txt1_Validate(Cancel As Boolean)
If Txt1.Text = "" Then
    MsgBox "no text in txt1"
    Txt1.SetFocus
End If
End Sub
```

This is the code I use. I click TAB on txt1 without entering any text, so this gets executed, but after msgbox, the focus gets set on txt2

Comment: I removed the `vb.net` tag. If your code is in legacy `vb6`, then it's definitely not related to `vb.net`.

Comment: @sstan fair enough! I thought it would be similar syntax.

Comment: Also removing the vba tag - it uses a slightly different control set.  That said, what type of control is it? `TabStrip`?  `SSTab`? Something else?

Comment: Do you have code in your Tab control's KeyPress event? I thought the default behaviour for tabbing was to cycle between fields on the current tab - not to move to next tab.

Comment: Or possible your txtcity lostfocus event?

Comment: @dbmitch no code for Key Press!

Comment: @dbmitch i do have a lostfocus event for txtcity - so basically what i did is i set a flag = False in my VALIDATE, and then when I do EXIT sub in case there's no text in one of my textboxes. now the next thing is LOST FOCUS txtcity and I basically do if flag=FALSE then exit sub. Maybe I should set the TABstuff.tab=0 THERE????!!??!?!?

Comment: Why not show ALL relevant code? Inside your question - not comments.

Comment: I have no idea why it's doing that. if i run the same code on a control that is before the last - then it stays on that TAB. But the thing is I need to run it on the last CONTROL before it goes to next tab.

Comment: As dbmitch requested, show **ALL** relevant code. You also still haven't said which tab control you are using.

Comment: This is all the relevant code. I'm using SSTab. the only thing missing from here are PRIVATE SUB AND END SUB.

Comment: Have you tried setting Cancel = True?

Comment: Have you tried debugging with a breakpoint on `tabstuff.tab=0` line and then stepping thru to see what code is executing to set the tab index back to 1. We can't do that here. You can also put a watch on `TabStuff.Tab=1` that breaks when expression is true. All we can do is guess based on what you've shown above

Comment: @dbmitch i went through the code, and it doesn't say set the TAB =1. The only reason it goes to Tab = 1 is because the first control on that tab has tab index incremented by 1 - so it's the next control to have focus when you TAB off txtCity. I don't know how to stop it. No freaking clue. It's so annoying and looks so unprofessional when it just changes tab but you want it to set focus on the control that doesn't have data but is required. it just so happens to be the last control on Tab=0

Comment: I have not worked with this control in years.  What about the SelectedItem property?  [here's some code to test](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_select_tabstrip_tab.html)

Comment: @JimmySmith - tha tworks with vb.net - selectedItem is not a property in VB6. It's supposed to work when i set it like this     Tabstuff.Tab = 0, however it has to do with tabIndex, since I'm tabbing off txtCity and the next control is on the other Tab - seems that tabIndex wins over my telling it to go to Tabstuff.tab=0. THANK YOU

Comment: @Bobski - What service pack are you running?

Comment: @JimHewitt not sure tbh

Comment: @Bobski - In the IDE Help>About Visual Basic.  Should be on the first line in parenthesis

Comment: @JimHewitt SP6 32 Bit

Comment: this seems to be the issue with all controls. Say I have txtbox1 - when users tabs to next control - say txtbox2 - that's when I run a check on txtbox1 to see if value was typed, and if not - i tell it to set focus to txtbox1, but the focus goes to txtbox2

Comment: Can you reproduce the behavior with a new project?

Comment: @JimHewitt please see EDIT 2

Comment: @Bobski - Instead of `Txt1.SetFocus` you should use `Cancel = True` as jac suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some extremely weird reason - i seem to have been getting this discrepancy because I was doign it in the VALIDATE property. When i entered the same code in LostFOCUS it seems to work fine. Thanks everyone for your help with this!

Comment: You shouldn't do `setFocus` in Validate event; either do that in LostFocus event, or set `Cancel = True` instead.